# how can I assign a value to an empty spot in a sparse matrix of type scipy csr

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with a huge matrix of type csr using SciPy. Sparse, and I want to add a value to an empty spot that's never used or assigned to when the matrix was created, without converting it to dense matrix. I have the desired row, col&data values but I just don't know how to access that specific element and add the value to it

**update:**
I tried this method but I get a weird "kernel error" and It doesn't work, assume: (we are at row k)

```
data(of row k) =np.insert(data,index,5)
col(indices of the row)=np.insert(col,index, colIndex)
row[k+1:] +=1
```

I cant understand what did I do wrong.

Comment: Spend some time reading the scipy.sparse docs, including several of the formats.  Pay attention to what methods they implement, including indexing.  And the pros/cons.  Practice with some small matrices, and look at how the attributes change when you do things.

Comment: @hpaulj I literally started doing python 1 month ago and I'm asking oddly specific questions because I have to work on this specific issue for a uni course project that's worth 40% and Its due in 2 days. I'm doing my best to learn about (Python+sparse matrices+ CSR scheme and a lot of new concepts to me in a very short time. mind you that I was assigned this touch task a week ago, never got the chance to prepare for it so I'm learning while working on it. telling me to spend some time "reading" is not actually an answer to my question. thank you for your concern but I'm doing my best "reading"

Comment: A course that expects you to learn Python and this specific module in a short time on your own, strikes me a poorly designed course.  SO is a good place to get debugging help.  But you seem to want something other than the obvious `M[i,j] =v`, possibly because of some misunderstanding.  It's hard to diagnose such a thing.

Comment: @hpaulj can you please check the update on the post

Comment: That's a new question.  A `kernel error` suggests a memory full issue, but you don't provide enough context to reproduce or test it.  Plus I don't like to debug that kind of problem.

Comment: @hpaulj not about debugging, but is( np.insert) a valid way to insert elements into a csr?

Answer (score 0):

A sample csr matrix:

```
In [66]: M = (sparse.random(5,5,.2,'csr')*10).astype(int)
In [67]: M
Out[67]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [69]: M.A
Out[69]: 
array([[0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Look at its attributes:

```
In [70]: M.indptr
Out[70]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5], dtype=int32)
In [71]: M.indices
Out[71]: array([2, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
In [72]: M.data
Out[72]: array([4, 2, 0, 3, 6])
```

Now use indexing to create a new nonzero value:

```
In [73]: M[2,3] = 12
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:82: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
```

Look at the new attributes - all the 3 have changed.

```
In [74]: M.indptr
Out[74]: array([0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 6], dtype=int32)
In [75]: M.indices
Out[75]: array([2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
In [76]: M.data
Out[76]: array([ 4,  2,  0, 12,  3,  6])
```

Values in `indptr` have changed, and values have been added to `indices` and `data`.  While I have a general idea of what is happening, I have not worked out the details.

As the warning says, it is easier to visualize, and perform an addition to a `lil` format matrix:

```
In [88]: Ml = M.tolil()
In [89]: Ml.rows
Out[89]: 
array([list([2]), list([0, 1, 3, 4]), list([1, 2, 4]), list([0, 1, 3]),
       list([])], dtype=object)
In [90]: Ml.data
Out[90]: 
array([list([5]), list([3, 0, 5, 1]), list([12, 1, 8]), list([7, 4, 8]),
       list([])], dtype=object)
In [91]: Ml.rows[2].append(3)
In [92]: Ml.data[2].append(23)
In [93]: Ml.A
Out[93]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  5,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  0,  0,  5,  1],
       [ 0, 12,  1, 23,  8],
       [ 7,  4,  0,  8,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```